# Color variation task

Tags: combinatorics

folks.
I have a 2x2 grid where each cell can be either black or white. How many variations of the grid can be built from this set?

I've tried manually count this and got 2 for 1x1 grid and 16 for 2x2 grid.
[image]

But how to applicate the math for this. What if I want to calculate the same variations for 3x3 or even 10x10 grids?

Comment: Each cell has two choices: red or black. Thus for $n$ cells, there are $2^n$ possibilities. In the case that we have a square grid, i.e $n^2$, this is then $2^{n^2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options for each cell. With $4$ total cells, you get $2^4 = 16$. For a $3×3$, you would have $9$ total cells, resulting in $2^9 = 512$.

Answer (score 2):

In the general case of a $n × n$ grid you have $2^{(n^2)}$ possibilities, the process to get this number is to think about that you have $n^2$ cells either black or white, so there are $2$ possibilities for every cell: you can visualize a tree with every layer representing the n-th cell and every branch representing a different sequence to understand what is the total number of possibilities :

```
  1° cell            w/     \b
  2° cell          w/ \b   w/ \b
  ...              /\ /\   /\ /\
  ...
```